# Joining two tables to fetch count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, subquery

I've two tables with the following schema

```
GROUP_ID | PURCHASE_ID |ITEMS  ---> TABLE1
  1            21         X
  1            21         Y
  1            21         Z
  2            22         X


GROUP_ID  |CUSTOMER_ID |ITEMS  --->TABLE2
1             ABC        X
1             ABC        Y
1             ABC        Z
1             ABC        A
1             ABC        B
```

A single GROUP_ID and PURCHASE_ID can have multiple items and similarly a single GROUP_ID and CUSTOMER_ID can have multiple ITEMS.The number of items bought will be only two or three per GROUP_ID and per PURCHASE_ID but a given CUSTOMER_ID,GROUP_ID can have a n number of items.

I want to query for each GROUP_ID and PURCHASE_ID and ITEMS[set], how many customers have bought at least all the ITEMS.

```
select distinct GROUP_ID,PURCHASE_ID,count(object_id)over(partition by GROUP_ID,PURCHASE_ID) from 
        (select a.GROUP_ID GROUP_ID,a.PURCHASE_ID PURCHASE_ID,b.CUSTOMER_ID object_id from      
        (select GROUP_ID,PURCHASE_ID,items,count(items)over(partition by GROUP_ID,PURCHASE_ID) val from  TABLE1)a,
        (select GROUP_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,ITEMS from TABLE2)b
        where a.GROUP_ID=b.GROUP_ID and a.items=b.ITEMS and val=3
        group by a.GROUP_ID,a.PURCHASE_ID,b.CUSTOMER_ID
        having count(*)=3)
```

For the above given data for GROUP_ID=1 and PURCHASE_ID=21 the count should be 1 since there exists a customer with ID ABC who has the subset of items [X,Y,Z]
I've written code to fetch the count of customers for three items as above. Is there any way to optimize this or achieve this.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Your question can benefit heavily from providing example data for each table and then expected output.

Comment: @Anand I've added expected input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one; I usually join the two tables on all the required columns and look for distinct counts to match like so:

```
select t1.group_id,
    t1.purchase_id,
    count(distinct t2.customer_id) as customer_count
from Table1 as t1
inner join Table2 as t2
on t2.group_id = t1.group_id
and t2.items = t1.items
group by t1.group_id,
    t1.purchase_id
having count(distinct t2.items) >= count(distinct t1.items)
```

This is untested so try it and let me know if it works or not.